# Cache that includes both lazy and non-lazy properties in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, associations, ehcache

The Grails documentation states, that

```
class Person {
    ..
    static mapping = {
        table 'people'
        cache true
    }
}
```

"will configure a 'read-write' cache that includes both lazy and non-lazy properties."

In case when we have one-to-many relationship in Person, ex:

```
static hasMany = [addressess: Address]
```

Does grails treat it as lazy property? 
Are Address object also cached, or only ids related to given Person are kept in cache?

Answer (score 5):

By default, associations are treated as `lazy` in Grails.

In the particular example above for `Person`, `all` address objects will be cached. The above default cache setting can be expanded to look like:

```
cache usage: 'read-write', include: 'all' //includes lazy and non-lazy
```

In order to cache only the association inside `Person`, you would need

`addresses cache: true`

In order to discard association from caching in `Person`, you would need

```
cache usage: 'read-write', include: 'non-lazy' 
//usage can be according to the need 'read-only', 'read-write', etc
```

Comment: I have grails melody plugin installed, where I can check what is in ehcache. With mapping done like in grails docs - just 'cache true' I can see Person cache in melody raport, but no Address cache. If, what you wrote is true, why I cannot see Address cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Gorm with Hibernate.

**Hibernate doesn't cache collections by default.** If you want to cache collections, you have to individually mark each of them to be cached.

```
static mapping = {
    addresses cache: true
}
```